# Download Manager downloads HTML

Tags: android, html, session, download, android-download-manager

I am using the default Android DownloadManager in the application. So, when I download a file, there is a session parameter attached in the URL, if the session is invalid or expired the user needs to login.

In my case, when the session is valid, I am able to donwload file. Else it downloads an HTML file.

Can anyone please help me out on this. I have attached the code for same below:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(arrayListDownloadProduct.get(position).getDownload_link() + "&SID=" + CommonMethods.getSessionId(mContext));
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setTitle(arrayListDownloadProduct.get(position).getTitle());
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
    request.setDescription("Downloading music file..");
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    Long reference = downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Is your server sending an html page when the session is expired? If so you need to handle that and by pass the Download manager to re-login before. If not download manager will download the server reply even if it's html

Comment: Actually, I am unable to get to know when the session is expired as when the HTML download is completed, then only we come to know that the session has expired. How can we see whether the HTML is being download ed or any other file type at the start of the download only.

Comment: Is your server replying with a 401 or 403 code when the session expires? If so the download manager will receive an error and you will be able to handle the login